# jQuery load()/event delegation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-delegation

Ok, I've just found out about event delegation, [Click Issue: Dynamically Generated Links Not Triggering Click Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581318/jquery-click-issue#17581372) my issue here is as follows.

The UL is loaded in via a jQuery load() call.

```
<ul id="activityPaganation" class="paganation">
    <li>1</li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first piece of jQuery will load in the above UL with paganation links. The second part of jquery gets the paganation page number from the paganation link you click, now the issue:

I can't get the the updated page loaded into `#accountActivity` once you click on a paganation link, is this a delegation issue or is what I'm trying to do just not possible, are the paganation links not able to see `#accountActivity` as this is where the inital load is loaded into?!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#accountActivity')) {
       $('#accountActivity').load('ajax.php?id=3');
    }

    $(document).on("click", "#activityPaganation li a", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var pid = $(this).text();
       $('#accountActivity').load('ajax.php?id=3&value='+pid);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: What's your network tab say?

Comment: Network tab seems to be calling the ajax.php file, response of 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#accountActivity')) {
       $('#accountActivity').load('ajax.php?id=3');
    }

    $('#activityPaganation').on("click", "li a", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var pid = $(this).text();
       $.post('ajax.php',{id:'3',value:pid},function(response) {
            $('#accountActivity').html(response);
       });
    });
});
```

IF `#activityPaganation` is not dynamically created.

Comment: pretty sure that should be $.get, he used $.load and the POST method is used only if data is provided as an object, otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: pretty sure it will work either way. I almost always use `$.post` for testing and then change it to `$.get`.

Comment: This clears out `#accountActivity` and if I change it use $.get is doesn't do anything.

Comment: That means you're not getting the response you're expecting from `ajax.php`. Check your console and see what's going on.

Comment: Got it, you had `value` in your snippet above, it was looking for `val`, thank you so much for your help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea, just syntax seems a little off to me. I'm winging it here, and somewhat of a jQuery noob, so bear with me if it doesn't work:

Change the second block of code to :

```
$('#activityPaganation li a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var pid = $(this).text();
   $('#accountActivity').load('ajax.php?id=3&value='+pid);
});
```

I always use alerts() as well to find out if its picking up certain variables. Try putting an alert after you assign a value to pid (i.e.: alert(pid);). If it's blank, you know it's not being assigned properly. If it doesn't show up at all, there is trouble before it.

Comment: He has to use `.on()` (delegated event) because of the dynamic creation of the `li` elements.